# I want to embed mystream video in my wordpress site

Tags: customization, pages, videos, hosting

I want to embed [mystream](https://mystream.to/) videos in my wordpress site but when i paste the embed link in the editor, its say that they can't do that. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Who exactly says you can't do that - WordPress, or mystream? What does the embed link look like? Is it just a normal URL that WordPress, which WordPress would then use to fetch oEmbed data from mystream? (It would be useful to see that oembed data if you can capture it somehow.) Or is it a block of HTML, with a `<video>` tag or similar?

Comment: Yes Is it just a normal mystream URL video